# Testing for fixed effects correlation (collinearity) in MATLAB's Linear Mixed Effects Models (fitlme)

Tags: regression, mixed-model, matlab, multicollinearity

I'm using MATLAB's `fitlme` function to fit a linear mixed-effects model to a dataset. I understand that one of the assumptions for LME models is an absence of fixed-effects correlation (collinearity). However, I do not know the best way to test for this. Any suggestions on how to do this in MATLAB?

The output of the model has a "Coefficient Covariance" output, is that the right thing to be looking at? If so, what kind of covariance value should I be concerned about?